# Can the Tournament creator kick out undesired players before the Tournament starts?

Tags: clash-royale

Some guy in my clan accidentally started his first 100 gem tournament (to get the 100 gem, plus XP, plus card chance payback), but he forgot to tap Password Protected before he started it (even though we instructed him to do so several times).

The Tournament immediately filled with undesirables, then he hit the password protected button and set a password (and set  "Show to Clan" on as well).

The Tournament hasn't started yet; is there a way he can kick out the undesired players who are likely to crush the tournament?  I think he's out of luck (and a few free cards).

Comment: I think it's too late, but it is impossible to kick someone of a tournament.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kick feature is not implemented in current Tournaments.

Resources:

[ClashRoyaleArena](http://clashroyalearena.com/news/clash-royale-tournaments-feature), 
[reddit.com/r/ClashRoyale](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClashRoyale/comments/4rqt2g/kick_people_from_tournament/)